# build process in github actions completed with exit code 2

Tags: github-actions

When I was trying to run the git action to build a docker image, got the following error. Any insight into what went wrong? Thanks!

Here is the workflow yaml:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    paths:
    - 'python/*'
      
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Python 3.7
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.7
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r ./python/requirements.txt
    - name: Build & Push Image
      run: |
        cd ./python
        echo "${{ secrets.DOCKERPW }}" | docker login -u "[your dockerhub login here]" --password-stdin
        docker image build -t [your dockerhub username here]/gitops:hellov1.0 .
        docker push [your docker hub username here]/gitops:hellov1.0
```

the error message in the log:

```
Run cd ./python
cd ./python
echo *** | docker login -u xsqian --password-stdin
docker image build -t xsqian/gitops:hellov1.0 .
docker push xsqian/gitops:hellov1.0
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
env:
pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.11/x64
/home/runner/work/_temp/30d82465-db58-4fc4-8139-ed8d8f5762d6.sh: line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Comment: I would first suggest to use actions/checkout@v2.3.4 (many things changed since version 1). Regarding the error, it seems to be related to the `"` on the second line of your last step. Did you substitute the dockerhub login variable keeping them?

Comment: The error are from your `Build & Push Image` task because your docker user and password might has some special character and because of that some extra `"` in the bash/sh. Make use of this [example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/publishing-docker-images) for docker build and push to any kind of docker registry.  with this, you no need to deal with any command-line way of build and push and do not need to worry about any special character in your username and password.

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel actually I found out in my docker hub password there is a special character " in it which caused the issue. Thanks for the example.

Comment: You should add an official answer to your question xsqian as you found the solution :)